# How to join all the txt files that are inside a directory? (Respecting that all lines are one below the other)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file, txt

I use this code to list all those txt that are in the directory of the indicated path

```py
from glob import glob

path_directory = 'Part001/*.txt'
list_files = glob(path_directory)

for f in list_files:
    print(f)
```

I need help to be able to merge all the listed txt into a single txt that contains all the text lines. Something like this:

In `31Aug21.txt`

```
Hello
Hello!
Hello, Tell me about something
```

In `04Sep21.txt`

```
Computer equipment has evolved in recent decades.
Perfect Orbit
```

In `05Sep21.txt`

```
The sky is blue
the computer is really useful
```

And all the lines of the listed txt should be written in a new txt, like this:

```
Hello
Hello!
Hello, Tell me about something
Computer equipment has evolved in recent decades.
Perfect Orbit
The sky is blue
the computer is really useful
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with reading the files...:

```
from glob import glob

path_directory = 'Part001/*.txt'
list_files = glob(path_directory)

lst = []
for fname in list_files:
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        lst.append(f.read())

with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newf:
    newf.write('\n'.join(lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from glob import glob

path_directory = 'Part001/*.txt'
list_files = glob(path_directory)

final = open('final_file.txt')
for f in list_files:
    with open(f) as fo:
        text = fo.read()
    final.write(text) #can add \n after this if you want - text+'\n'

final.close()
```